# Ubuntu unity cannot work, reinstall didn't fix

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-unity

I am using OdroidXu4 armv7 board, ubuntu 16.04. Dont know why my all menu disappear, but the files on desktop can still be operated. 
I followed https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/ to reinstall ubuntu-destop or unity, but it didn't work.
Then I used the command below

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
setsid unity
```

The menu flashed a while then disappeared again, returned error:

```
file /dev/mali0 is not of a compatible version (user 10.6, kernel 10.1)
ERROR: The DDK is not compatible with any of the Mali GPUs on the system.
The DDK was built for 0x620 r0p1 status range [0..15], but none of the GPUs 
matched:
file /dev/mali0 is not of a compatible version (user 9.0, kernel 8.0)
```

I was confused with the "GPUs", because I didn't have any GPU. 
How to fix the problem, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ubuntu 16.04.In my case unity, launcher and even terminal is not working.I followed the steps as described in https://www.itsmearunchandel.co.in/linux/ubuntu/how-to-reset-ubuntu-desktop.html .
1. Go to command line mode, press Ctrl+Alt+F1
2. Give username and password.
3. Run the commands as described in the link.

This way my issue was resolved.